# XML parsers failed to an xml file with &qt;

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I have XML file which include the following line:

```
<span class="page-normal" id="page_0007"><A href="bwxy0003.smil#page_0007" &gt;>4</A></span>
```

I have used QXmlStreamReader, QDomDocument, QXmlSimpleReader, libxml2 and pugixml, but all fail on this line and especially at the "&qt;"

Is there an XML parser who will work with this or another solution is possible?

Thanks for the help

Comment: The line contains `&gt;` but your explanation contains `&qt;`. Which is actually used?

Comment: Also is this a valid XML?

Comment: Your XML seems malformed. Why is the `&gt;` there? `&gt;` means the greater-than symbol (`>`).

Comment: What is shown is not XML, it is HTML, or perhaps XHTML.  Either way, it makes no sense for `&gt;` to appear where it is, and having it appear there will break the syntax of XML/HTML, so it makes sense that an XML/HTML parser will fail on it.

Comment: Sorry it is "&gt;" I was wondering if one of the parser could ignore this and parse trough the xml..